# How to get all html content of the clicked control?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know how to get the content of the clicked control but now the situation is a bit complicated, in particular I've a container like this:

```
<div id='wizard-frame-1'>
 <div class="available_services">
      <div class="available_service-row" data-id="1">
            <strong>Taglio capelli</strong>
                <br>Durata: 20 - Prezzo: 50.00 €<br>
       </div><hr>
       <div class="available_service-row" data-id="2">
             <strong>Colore capelli</strong>
                 <br>Durata: 50 - Prezzo: 30.00 €<br>
       </div><hr>
       <div class="available_service-row" data-id="3">
             <strong>Trattamenti viso</strong>
                 <br>Durata: 30 - Prezzo: 15.00 €<br>
        </div><hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is a result of [JScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/)

Now what I'm trying to do is pass the selected row `available_service-row` to another JScrollPane:

```
<div id='wizard-frame-1'>
     <div class="services_added"></div>
</div>
```

What I tried is this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#wizard-frame-1 .available_service-row', function()
{
      console.log($(this).html());
});
```

But the result returned is this:

```
<strong>Colore capelli</strong><br>Durata: 50 - Prezzo: 30.00 €<br>
```

How you can see there is only the content of the clicked div row, I need to get also the parent container, so the div, in this case I'm waiting this result:

```
<div class="available_service-row" data-id="1">
       <strong>Taglio capelli</strong>
       <br>Durata: 20 - Prezzo: 50.00 €<br>
</div>
```

I don't know if this is a correct way to do this. For example when I used the `select` I can copy the option like `.clone()` method, but now the situation is different. Suggestions?

Comment: You are looking for outerHTML property

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get element outerHTML:

```
this.outerHTML
```

In jq (for code consistency while using jQuery):

```
$(this).prop('outerHTML');
```

Comment: I didn't know this property, thanks for this! Have a good day :)